# Vuforia how to play my video Playback demo is crashing

Tags: ios, video, vuforia

I am able to run `Vuforia` demo application for play back but it is crashing when I click on start button on this line in code

```
[context presentRenderbuffer:GL_RENDERBUFFER]
```

if I explicitly return true in it then it is showing this message on console

`Unable to bind video background texture!!`

Can any one help me how can I play on own video in it.

Thanks

Comment: Did you find Any solution?

Comment: yes see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

yes 
1. when I am running it with device connected then it is crashing we need to run and then disconnect the device and then try to run it. it is solving my problem.
or 
2. Try it with another devices it is working...
or 
3. Try with another Xcode that is below to 9.0.

In above all 3 situations it is working.